# What is the difference between JSON notation and assigning to an object?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

On the [Twitter Client](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/twitter.html) example at Knockoutjs some properties are in the JSON object and others are assigned outside the JSON variable. What is the difference? Why can't the methods (`findSavedList`) just be a part of the initial declaration?

```
var viewModel = {
    savedLists: ko.observableArray([ ... ]),
    editingList: { ...  },
    userNameToAdd : ko.observable(""),
    currentTweets : ko.observableArray([])
};

viewModel.findSavedList = function (name) {
   ...
};
```

Comment: Your viewModel is not a JSON object.

Comment: That's not JSON. See http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So is viewModel just an object literal?

Comment: @Tom: Yes. It's an object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the code in the question, I don't see any reason it couldn't have been written like so:

```
var viewModel = {
    savedLists: ko.observableArray([ ... ]),
    editingList: { ...  },
    userNameToAdd : ko.observable(""),
    currentTweets : ko.observableArray([]),
    findSavedList: function (name) {
       ...
    }
};
```

Looking at the [actual example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/twitter.html), I think they just wanted to write the functions separately — maybe for readability?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that methods can't; it's stylistic.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the things you've quoted is JSON. JSON is a textual notation for data exchange. What you've quoted is JavaScript code.

To answer your question, there's no reason that the function couldn't have been defined within the object literal:

```
var viewModel = {
    savedLists: ko.observableArray([ ... ]),
    editingList: { ...  },
    userNameToAdd : ko.observable(""),
    currentTweets : ko.observableArray([]),
    findSavedList: function(name) {
       ...
   }
};
```

The author may have broken them up for clarity.

---

About my JSON comment above: JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal notation. The above is straight JavaScript literal notation. You never need JSON inside JavaScript code; you only need JSON when you're passing data around encoded in textual form. If it *were* meant to be JSON, it would be invalid. In JSON, property names (keys) must be in double quotes, and you can't have expressions on the right-hand side of a property initializer (so, no calling `ko.observeableArray`). More on the [JSON site](http://json.org).

Comment: To add to your comments: JSON also cannot contain functions.

Comment: @Matt: Well, those would be expressions. :-) But still worth calling out.